# Java WebApp with OAuth to Azure AD - get profile pic?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-active-directory

I've created a SpringBoot application which authenticates users against my company's Azure Active Directory server using OAuth 2.0

Now I'd like to display the User's profile picture.

The first way I went about this was to naively embed the graph API url to the user's profile picture in an IMG tag, assuming that the browser's cookies would implicitly provide authentication for the logged-in user:

```
<img src="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/48x48/$value"/>
```

but this results in a 401 error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "71fe8fc9-e8d2-4f2e-950d-04e7d9fa64e6",
      "date": "2018-09-24T07:08:50"
    }
  }
}
```

what's the best way to get the User's profile picture after AD/OAuth authentication - I'm happy to do this either by the client-side or server-side, and ideally I'd like to know both approaches

Answer (score 0):

You could do it client-side, but you'd need to acquire an access token with ADAL.JS/MSAL.JS and then request for the file and set it as the content of the img element via JavaScript.

Server-side is probably easier to implement, point the img to an HTTP route in your back-end, acquire an access token, call the API, and return the bytes of the image as a result from the route.

Comment: OK but how can I acquire an access-token for the User on the server-side when they have authenticated in via OAuth?

Comment: Use a token cache. After the user authenticates, you can exchange the authorization code for an access token and a refresh token. Cache these, and you can use the refresh token to get a new access token and refresh token. I'm not sure how this is exactly implemented in Java since I work with .NET :)

Comment: I follow your meaning - do you have a reference to c# code that exchanges the authorization code for an access token?

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth/blob/master/Core2AadAuth/Startup.cs#L75